# Tensorflow can't determine why size of tensor is changing and can't debug directly

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am creating a convolutional neural network class using tensorflow and have run into an error where, during optimization, one tensor has 40000 elements when it should only have 10000. The problem arises in the line:

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.y, 1), tf.argmax(output, 1))
```

giving the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [10000] vs. [40000]
 [[Node: Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](ArgMax, ArgMax_1)]]
```

so basically it's saying that the output of my network is 4x larger than the test labels I provided it. My question is how do I view the size of my output tensor as it changes? It seems like everything happens behind the scenes via the single line of code session.run('model-name') which prevents me from being able to debug it. How do I peek inside and figure out what's going on?

Here is the full code:

```
class ConvNet:
    def __init__(self, epochs=1, learning_rate=0.01, batch_size=50):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
    self.x_shaped = tf.reshape(self.x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    self.y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

    self.accuracy = None

def predict(self, x_test, y_test):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('convnet-model.meta')
        new_saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
        test_acc = sess.run(self.accuracy, feed_dict={self.x: x_test, self.y: y_test})
        print('test accuracy: {:.3f}'.format(test_acc))

def train(self, x_train, y_train):
    output, raw_output = self.create_structure()
    self.optimize(raw_output, output, x_train, y_train)

def create_structure(self):

    output = self.conv_layer(self.x_shaped, 1, 32, [5, 5], 'conv1')
    output = self.relu_layer(output)
    output = self.conv_layer(output, 32, 64, [5, 5], 'conv2')
    output = self.relu_layer(output)
    output = self.max_pool_layer(output, [2, 2])
    raw_output, output = self.full_connect_layers(output)

    return output, raw_output

def optimize(self, raw_output, output, x_train, y_train):

    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=raw_output, labels=output))
    optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.y, 1), tf.argmax(output, 1))
    self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        sess.run(init_op)
        total_batch = int(len(y_train) / self.batch_size)
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):

            for i in range(total_batch):

                batch_x, batch_y = self.get_batch(x_train, y_train) 
                _, c = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy], feed_dict={self.x: batch_x, self.y: batch_y})

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(sess, './convnet-model')

def conv_layer(self, input_data, num_input_channels, num_filters, filter_shape, name):

    # setup the filter shape for tf.nn.conv2d
    conv_filter_shape = [filter_shape[0], filter_shape[1], num_input_channels, num_filters]

    # init weights and bias for the filter
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(conv_filter_shape, stddev=0.03), name=name+'_w')
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_filters]), name=name+'_b')

    # set up the convolutional layer operation
    out_layer = tf.nn.conv2d(input_data, weights, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

    # add the bias
    out_layer += bias

    return out_layer

def relu_layer(self, out_layer):

    return tf.nn.relu(out_layer)

def max_pool_layer(self, out_layer, pool_shape):

    ksize = [1, pool_shape[0], pool_shape[1], 1]
    strides = [1, 2, 2, 1]
    out_layer = tf.nn.max_pool(out_layer, ksize=ksize, strides=strides, padding='SAME')

    return out_layer

def full_connect_layers(self, output):

    flattened = tf.reshape(output, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])

    w1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([7*7*64, 1000], stddev=0.03), name='w1')
    b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1000], stddev=0.01), name='b1')

    dense_layer1 = tf.matmul(flattened, w1) + b1
    dense_layer1 = tf.nn.relu(dense_layer1)

    w2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1000, 10], stddev=0.03), name='w2')
    b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10], stddev=0.01), name='b2')

    dense_layer2 = tf.matmul(dense_layer1, w2) + b2
    y = tf.nn.softmax(dense_layer2)
    return dense_layer2, y

def get_batch(self, features, labels):
    index_list = np.arange(0, len(labels))
    np.random.shuffle(index_list)
    new_features = np.asarray([features[i] for i in index_list])
    new_labels = np.asarray([labels[i] for i in index_list])

    return new_features[0:self.batch_size], new_labels[0:self.batch_size]
```

main file:

```
from convnet import ConvNet
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

convnet = ConvNet()
convnet.train(mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels)
convnet.predict(mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels)
```

Comment: Better than answering the question "how do I debug my code", why not provide your code so it can be debugged here?

Comment: added the code, any ideas on the issue?